# How to write a post method which accepts JSON in Nancy and how to call it form a C# client?

Tags: c#, rest, mono, nancy

I wrote following module in Nancy

```
    public class CategoryModule : NancyModule
{
    public CategoryModule()
    {
        //At this moment just Show Hello world
        Get["/"] = _ => { return "Nancy says hello!"; };
        //Get["/"] = parameters => "Hello World!";
        GetCategories();
        SetCategory();
    }


     void GetCategories()
    {
        Get["/Catergories"] = _ =>
        {

            var catergoryRepository = new CategoryRepository();
            var categorycollection = catergoryRepository.GetCategoryInfo();
            return Negotiate.WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK).WithModel(categorycollection.ToArray());
        };
    }

     void SetCategory()
     {
         Post["/Catergories/{categryName:string}"] = _ =>
         {
             var catergoryModel = this.Bind<Category>();
             catergoryModel.PK_CategoryId = Guid.NewGuid();
             catergoryModel.CategoryName = _;
             return HttpStatusCode.OK;
         };
     }
}
```

I am using chrome POSTMAN to test the Module.I can get the break point in **"GetCategories()"**  if i  call **http://192.168.1.4:8888/Categories** in POSTMAN. 
But i couldn't get break point in **SetCategory()** if i call **http://192.168.1.4:8888/Catergories/categryName=test**. I am new  to Nancy and not sure that my post method is correct.

could any one provide

1. An example to a Post method which accept Jason as parameter
2. An example to call it form client side

I couldn't find a simple example for above in their documentation.

***Note***

I am using Self hosting environment where i am hosting nancy with following code

```
var server = new Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost(new Uri("http://192.168.1.4:8888"));
```

And following is the category model

```
    public class Category
{
    public Guid PK_CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Add your `Category` class code, please.

Comment: @RomanDibikhin Thanks.I updated the code for  category class as well!

Comment: Ok, I will try to reproduce your problem tomorrow.

Comment: @RomanDibikhin Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to post JSON with POSTMAN you should add headers with JSON content type, as [docs](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Model-binding#deserializing-rich-request-body-payloads) say (third paragraph). Set up POSTMAN:

1. Set your host to `http://192.168.1.4:8888/Categories` and select `POST`.
2. Add headers with `Content-Type` and `application/json` as header and value 
   respectively.
3. Set `raw` and set `JSON` as type.
4. Put this `{ "CategoryName": "something" }` as is in a text field below.
5. Hit "Send".

Comment: @Thabo Thank you for a feedback ;) It's cool to help each other.